# Packing all .class file in a single jar before deploying GAE app?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am using GAE plugin for eclipse and wanted to know if the plugin takes care of packing every class files in a single jar before deployement ?

I've heard that application performance can be slow if we have lot of class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use maven for build and dependency definition rather than Eclipse and the Google plugin. But generally if you have a single module in your project all the code for this will be built into a single jar file and bundled into a .war file together with all the jars defined in your dependencies.